# mysql select query only showing one data in php

Tags: php, sql, select

so I'm trying to show data from my sql table. There are two data but only one of them shows when I try to open my php page. here's my codes :

```
<?php
    include ("koneksi.php");

    // $username=$_GET['username'];
    $username="Dia";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_penyakit_user WHERE username='Dia'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

    echo " penyakit: ".$row['penyakit'];

?>
```

I tried to run the select query on phpmyadmin an it showed 2 data. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to fetch the second row - this is typically done in a loop

Comment: you need a while loop to iterate over the array

Comment: If any answer really helpful to you than please accept it.

Comment: Also you could consider looking into PDO in PHP. One of my personal favorites when working wih databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` only gets one array at a time. To properly get all available rows, put it in a while-loop like so:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo " penyakit: " . $row['penyakit'];
}
```

As an aside, however, please note that the mysql_* functions are considered deprecated, and should not be used in future development. (Here's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/899126))

Answer (score 1):

You have to use while loop while more than one row.

```
<?php
    include ("koneksi.php");
    // $username=$_GET['username'];
    $username="Dia";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_penyakit_user WHERE username='Dia'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
        echo " penyakit: ".$row['penyakit'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * tbl_penyakit_user WHERE username='Dia'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['penyakit'];
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
 include ("koneksi.php");

// $username=$_GET['username'];
 $username="Dia";

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_penyakit_user WHERE username='Dia'");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )){
     echo " penyakit: ".$row['penyakit'];
}

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch each row so use a `while` loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo " penyakit: ".$row['penyakit'];
}
```

This should output all rows, you only fetch one.